# The data is not received after the Internet is recovering

Tags: android, rx-java, android-livedata

I'm using RxJava3 and Live data.

I'm calling methos getAllMovies and getAllGenres in background thread, then set the received data to MutableLiveData.

In my splash activity I'm calling these methods from viewModel.

I have lottie animation , and each time lottie animation end, I'm checking if data received , if yes , opening another activity, else, waiting again for data receive.

The problem is when I lose internet connection , data is not received after the Internet is recovering.

I'm trying to run app when the wifi and internet is off, and then turning on wifi.

But always getting 0 in methods size.

If I running the app with internet on , data received normally.

That what I have.

App repository:

```
private MutableLiveData<List<GenreResult>> mGenresResponseMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public MutableLiveData<List<GenreResult>> getGenresResponseMutableLiveData() {
        AppService appService = RetrofitInstance.getService();
        appService.getAllGenres(mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key),
                mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.language))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<GenreResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(GenreResponse genreResponses) throws Throwable {
                        mGenresResponseMutableLiveData.setValue(genreResponses.getGenreResults());
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
                        Toast.makeText(mApplication.getApplicationContext(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        return mGenresResponseMutableLiveData;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class GenresViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private AppRepository mRepository;

    public GenresViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new AppRepository(application);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<GenreResult>> getGenreLiveData() {
        return mRepository.getGenresResponseMutableLiveData();
    }
}
```

SplashActivity calling getGenre method:

```
private void getGenreList() {
    mGenreResultArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    mGenresViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(GenresViewModel.class);
    mGenresViewModel.getGenreLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<GenreResult>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<GenreResult> genreResults) {
            mGenreResultArrayList = (ArrayList<GenreResult>) genreResults;
        }
    });
}
```

SplashActivity checking on lottie listener if data received:

```
private void initViews() {
        mLAVLoader = findViewById(R.id.lavLoader);
        mLAVLoader.addAnimatorListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                if (mGenreResultArrayList != null && mGenreResultArrayList.size() > 0
                        && mMovieResultArrayList != null && mMovieResultArrayList.size() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("genreList", mGenreResultArrayList);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("moviesList", mMovieResultArrayList);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    mLAVLoader.playAnimation();
                    Log.d("myDebug", "onAnimationEnd: " + mGenreResultArrayList.size()+ " "+mMovieResultArrayList.size());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with retryWhen method in Repository:

```
 public MutableLiveData<List<MovieResult>> getAllMoviesMutableLiveData() {
        AppService appService = RetrofitInstance.getService();
        appService.getAllMovies(mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key),
                mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.language),
                "popularity.desc")
                .retryWhen(throwable ->
                        throwable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<MoviesResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) throws Throwable {
                        mAllMoviesMutableLiveData.setValue(moviesResponse.getMovieResults());
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
                    }
                });
        return mAllMoviesMutableLiveData;
    }
```